# Javascript scroll animation cuts off page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using a javascript smooth scrolling animation for my wordpress ecommerce website https://harperaustralia.com/ as demonstrated on https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothScrollAnimations/

However, the scroll discontinues before the bottom of the page and cuts off the last few lines of content and the footer. I need to zoom in and out before it can continue scrolling to the bottom of the page. This does not seem to be a problem in the demo.

The HTML is spread across header.php, page.php and footer.php files and includes a fixed container while the [data-scroll] div will get translated.

```
<main>
<div id="nav">navigation and logo here</div><!-- /END NAV -->
<div data-scroll>
<div id="header"></div><!-- /END HEADER -->
<div id="content">

<?php
    wp_reset_query(); // necessary to reset query
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

</div><!-- /END CONTENT -->
<div id="footer">footer content here</div><!-- /END FOOTER -->
</div><!-- /END DATA SCROLL -->
</main>
```

The relevant css is

```
[data-scroll] {
    will-change: transform;
}


element.style {

    transform: matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 600);
    transform-origin: 100% 50% 0px;
    opacity: 1
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
overscroll-behavior: none;
}

body {
    /* PADDING SAME AS FOOTER HEIGHT */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }


main {
animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The javascript is linked in the footer.php file

```
<script src="https://harperaustralia.com/wp-content/plugins/smoothscroll/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harperaustralia.com/wp-content/plugins/smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

I have tried changing the height of the container and removing html {scroll-behavior: smooth; } to see if there were conflicts but these did not fix the problem. I would really appreciate any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks

Comment: Sorry the <div id="nav"> is before <main>

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to get display height before all content is loaded. You should call your scrolling script once all content is loaded in order to prevent scroll cut off.

Look at your body tag in developer tools and you'll see it yourself.

```
<body style="height: 5096px;">
```

Other thing you can do is set overflow-y: scroll on body tag.

Comment: @aleska_95 thank you for your response. The body tag is already set to overflow-y: scroll, and the javascript file is loaded at the end of the footer.php file. In the javascript file it calculates the size of the viewport and recalculates on resize. Is there a way to change this?
`// body element
    const body = document.body;
    
    // calculate the viewport size
    let winsize;
    const calcWinsize = () => winsize = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    calcWinsize();
    // and recalculate on resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', calcWinsize);
`

Comment: Import first smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js and then /imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js not the other way around. If you look closely at imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js it returns a promise. So the other way would be waiting until promise is resolved and then calling smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js.

Comment: @aleska_95 unfortunately changing the script order in the footer.php to `<script src="https://harperaustralia.com/wp-content/plugins/smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://harperaustralia.com/wp-content/plugins/smoothscroll/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>` removes the scroll animation

Comment: @Milena I just double checked it and there are definitely promises that are not resolved before you load your script. Your instagram feed is taking the longest, but it is not he only one that takes time to resolve.  If you can't find a way around it use setTimeout to load your script after 1s, but I would not recommend that as a final solution.